# Are there any Male to Female DI2 wires / exetensions?

Tags: shimano-di2

I know you can use a junction port (ie: SM-JC41 Internal Junction Box B) for this, but are there any Male to Female extension cables?

Root Cause: R600 to 5 port junction for a TT setup near the base lever (Magura's so can't use the standard integrated TT brake/shifter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there are not any male-to-female "extension" wires available for the Shimano Di2 E-Tube system.  You can use a junction as you said, or you can use the two-port ANT module.  You could also modify an E-Tube wire to lengthen it yourself, if you are handy with a soldering iron.

Answer (score 2):

Extension (Male/Female) wires are now available since a few weeks.
You can ask your reseller, they are not on general availability yet.
I got one of them because I moved my aerobars forward and needed some more length

Cheers,

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se]! Thanks for answering one of our questions. We recommend that new members take the [tour] to make best use of the site, and since you're answering, [answer] will be helpful also. Again, welcome

Comment: Can you provide a link to an example of an extension cable that's now available? Thanks.